# ESRI backgrounds render with blocks of different color schemes

Tags: qgis, tiles, rendering, arcgis-online-basemaps, background

I'm creating a map covering the whole Europe, in EPSG3035, using QGIS Białowieża.
I'm using the "internet" extension to add "ESRI Ocean" as a background (the service is in epsg:3857).
This renders nicely in the main view.
However, if I try to make a poster with the "print composer", or even if I try to export my view into a pdf, then the background is not continuous anymore, but shows irregularity in the tint (block like, see attached image). Same problem if I remove the other layers and keep only the ESRI-Ocean backgroung.

Why is this happening, and how can I get a smooth display, like in the main view? Could it be an issue with the tiles re-projection?

[image]

Comment: What version of Arc?  Does the problem exist when you turn off all layers except Oceans?  What do you mean by "... the "internet" extension..."?  I can successfully export to pdf (ArcMap 10.8.2) in EPSG:3035 if I load Oceans using *Add Data > Basemaps > Oceans*.  I can also successfully export Oceans EPSG:3035 to pdf using QGIS 3.22.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say I'm using QGIS Białowieża! I've just edited my post. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: 1) What happens when you display *only* the Oceans?  2) What method are you using to load the Oceans layer into QGIS?

Comment: To display the "ESRI Ocean" background, I use QGIS extension "Internet", that lists a series of WMS. Actually, the display in the main ("canvas"?) view is perfect! I only have a problem when exporting to PDF (either directly from the main view, or by creating a map with the composer). I suspect that the tiles color range is handled differently by the main view and the export functions...

Comment: I'll ask for the third (and last) time: What happens when you display only the Oceans?

Comment: If I display only the oceans, I get exactly the same result: ok in the main view, "blocks" in the exports (from the view or from the composer). I must add that "ESRI Oceans" is in epsg:3857, while my project is in epsg:3035 (I'd not be surprised that the issue is related to the tiles reprojection).